# How do I reload an OS X "bash" user-environment

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, launchd

I think that I want to ask

- How do I reload an OS X `bash` user-environment

But damnit Jim ; I'm a software engineer not a sysadmin

## The Goal

- I want Jenkins started as a Daemon on El Capitan
- I want to use "UserWhoHasARealAccount" on OS X
- For this I should be using a launch-daemon

AFAIK

- all ***/Library/LaunchDaemons/*** are started as ***root***
- While they can substitute-user with ***User*** to become ***not-root*** they still retain *root's* environment.

## The Problem

- process won't have the full PATH (et al) that I setup

  - `which` can work around this but ...
- sub processes don't get the PATH I setup for the user

  - so `which whatever-i-want` doesn't help when Node.JS tries to run a subprocess and compile my blog ... unless I for Node.JS to invoke subprocesses via absolute paths on my computer
- the ***root*** environment seems to prevent `ssh` from working

  - so I can't have have "UserWhoHasARealAccount" login to localhost to magically get a real path
  - I may be missing something since I can't find any SSH error messages

Since this is a server, logging in and pressing a button won't "do it for me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone from the future ..

`bash` can be run with `-l` to execute full login goodies.
So, my launchd script goes from;

```
<ProgramArguments>
    <array>
        <string>java</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>jenkins.war</string>
    </array>
```

... to ...

```
<ProgramArguments>
    <array>
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>-l</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>java -jar jenkins.war</string>
    </array>
```